# Hide or close top level window when main window isn't visible

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to close or preferably hide a top-level window if the main window is not visible?

I was already able to do that by checking if the minimize button had been clicked. Still, there are several ways to "minimise" a window such as going into another tab, hitting the side of the taskbar (on windows) etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Try `<tkinter.Toplevel>.withdraw()` to hide the window, `<tkinter.Toplevel>.deiconify()` to show the window and `<tkinter.Toplevel>.iconnify()` to force the window to minimise itself

Comment: Yes but how can I do it so it will run every time the main window is not visible

Comment: Have you tried binding to `"<Map>"` and `"<Unmap>"`

Comment: You could also bind to `"<FocusOut>"` and `"<FocusIn>"` and create some logic to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try binding functions to `<Unmap>` and `<Map>` events of the window. Like below:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
for _ in range(3):
    Toplevel(root)

def hide_all(event):
    # You could also call each child directly if you have the object but since we aren't tracking
    # the toplevels we need to loop throught the children
    for child in root.children.values():
        if isinstance(child, Toplevel):
            child.withdraw() # or depending on the os: 'child.wm_withdraw()'

def show_all(event):
    # You could also call each child directly if you have the object but since we aren't tracking
    # the toplevels we need to loop throught the children
    for child in root.children.values():
        if isinstance(child, Toplevel):
            child.deiconify() # or depending on the os: 'child.wm_deiconify()'

root.bind("<Unmap>", hide_all) # Fires whenever 'root' is minimzed
root.bind("<Map>", show_all) # Fires whenever 'root' is restored and shown
root.mainloop()
```

If this isn't what you want, you may be able to use the `<Expose>` or `<Visibility>` events to get what you want. Link to all tkinter events: [tkinter events from anzeljg](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-types.html)